# How is this function continuous?

Tags: continuity, definition

The textbook stated that the following function whose domain is $\mathbb{R}$is continuous for every point in the domain:
$g(x)=1, 0\le x\le1$

$=2, 2\le x \le3$,
and it continues this patern.

What about the values between any two natural numbers? Shouldn't it be discontinuous there?

Page shot added after discussion in the comments:

[image]

Comment: Continuity is a concept which only makes sense on its domain. Since, for instance, $\dfrac 3 2$ isn't in the domain of $g$, you can't say that it $g$ is continuous there, but you can't say $g$ discontinuous there either. It simply doesn't make sense.

Comment: You claim the domain is $\mathbb R$ yet you don't indicate the definition of the function everywhere.

Comment: So the function is making values such as those between 1 and 2 nonapplicable?

Comment: @OscarFlores See [MPW](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/113214/mpw)'s [comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/770714/how-is-this-function-continuous#comment1600207_770714) and ignore mine until this is clarified.

Comment: @MPW I did type what the book says for $g(x)$. It gives the first two points and says that it is continuous for every point in its domain.

Comment: @OscarFlores Does it say the domain is $\mathbb R$?

Comment: I would suggest then that either the domain is not all of $\mathbb R$ (in which case @GitGud's comment holds) or that the author intends you to furnish any desirable continuous extension to all of $\mathbb R$ because the precise details are not relevant to his exposition (for example, extend the function to be piecewise linear and continuous).

Comment: @OscarFlores Can you give us a reference to which textbook this came from?

Comment: @GitGud Well the book ties in two examples with the same domain. It defines the domain as the reals for the function y=cx and then says "similarly, the function $g(x)$" and states what I typed in the question box. Unless I am mistaken, it appears that the domain for $g(x)$ is the reals.

Comment: @BrandonCarter the book is The Elements of Real Analysis by Robert G. Bartle page 139.

Comment: @OscarFlores Are you sure some of those $\leq$s shouldn't be $<$s?

Comment: @JackM I'm sure. The book has $\le$ not $<$

Comment: @OscarFlores If it really has $\leq$s everywhere, then the function isn't even well defined, since e.g. it should be equal to both $1$ and $2$ for $x=2$.

Comment: The book does not say that the domain of the function is $\mathbf{R}$, but rather implies that it is $[0,1] \cup [2,3]$, in which case the function is continuous.

Comment: @JackM You're misreading the function.

Comment: @GitGud Oh, I interpreted "it continues this pattern" to mean it was the integer part function.

Comment: @BrandonCarter oh okay. Thanks.

Comment: @BrandonCarter How do you add screenshots of pdfs into a question?

Comment: @OscarFlores You should ask me. I just take a screen shot, then go to paint, select the relevant part, cut, create new file, paste and save.

Comment: @GitGud I thought it was Brandon. Thanks.